# getting the object from mapAnnotaion and passing it with segue

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have an app that displays map of bars, and an infoBar view controller with details on every bar.

i present the locations on the map with annotation, and when i press on an annotation in want to segue to infoVc with that data.

How can i do it?

i'm using prepare and perform with segue, and tried to cast the annotation as a Bar object, but it didnt work...

prepare --

```
    let segueMapToInfo = "mapToDetail"
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == segueMapToInfo {
            let destVC = segue.destination as! InfoViewController
            destVC.infoBar = ???
        }
    }
```

perform --

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    let bar = view.annotation as? Bar
    print("sucess")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: segueMapToInfo, sender: bar)
}
```

in my infoVC i have an infoBar var to catch the data

note - when i try to transfer hard-coded bar (a sample bar i created) it worked, so the problem is in the casting the annotation as a generic bar object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use selected Annotation from didSelectAnnotationView, then store that annotation to instance variable and after that used annotation in your prepare(for segue: method.

```
var getSelectedAnnotation: Bar?

 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let getBar = view.annotation as? Bar{
     getSelectedAnnotation = getBar
     print("sucess")
     performSegue(withIdentifier: segueMapToInfo, sender: self)
    }
}

   let segueMapToInfo = "mapToDetail"
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == segueMapToInfo {
            let destVC = segue.destination as! InfoViewController
            destVC.infoBar = getSelectedAnnotation
        }
    }
```